# VBA Excel GoalSeek For a value

Tags: vba, excel

I would like for my code to find a value for **h** when **fx** is **equal to** **0**. Thus, I thought of using the GoalSeek method but I can't seem to crack it. I know I probably should've stored all of this operation in a function, but I'm fairly new to VBA.  Please help!

```
Option Explicit

Dim d As Double, h As Double, k As Double, p As Double
Dim Ag As Double, t As Double, Al As Double
Dim Sg As Double, Sl As Double, Si As Double, Pi As Double
Dim Dl As Double, ul As Double
Dim Dg As Double, ug As Double
Dim Reg As Double, Rel As Double
Dim taug As Double, taul As Double, taui As Double
Dim fg As Double, fl As Double, fi As Double, fx As Double
Dim rl As Double, rg As Double
Dim vsl As Double, vsg As Double
Dim mul As Double, mug As Double
Dim alpha As Double

Sub findhwhenfx=0()

    Pi = 3.14159265358979 'Fixed Value in Worksheet    
    t = Range("B1").Value 'Fixed Value in Worksheet    
    d = Range("B2").Value 'Fixed Value in Worksheet    
    h = Range("D12").Value 'Value to be found once I click run     
    vsl = Range("B4").Value 'Fixed Value in Worksheet    
    vsg = Range("B3").Value 'Fixed Value in Worksheet    
    mul = Range("B6").Value 'Fixed Value in Worksheet    
    mug = Range("B5").Value 'Fixed Value in Worksheet    
    rl = Range("B7").Value 'Fixed Value in Worksheet    
    rg = Range("B8").Value 'Fixed Value in Worksheet    
    alpha = Range("B9").Value 'Fixed Value in Worksheet 

    Range("U12").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D12")    
    k = (2 * h) - 1    
    p = Application.Acos(k)    
    Ag = (p - k * Sqr(1 - (k) ^ 2)) * (d) ^ 2 / 4    
    Range("E12").Value = Ag    
    Al = t - Ag    
    Range("F12").Value = Al    
    Sg = d * p    
    Range("G12").Value = Sg    
    Sl = (Pi * d) - Sg    
    Range("H12").Value = Sl    
    Si = d * Sqr(1 - k ^ (2))    
    Range("I12").Value = Si

    Dl = (4 * Al) / Sl    
    Range("J12").Value = Dl    
    ul = (vsl * t) / Al    
    Range("K12").Value = ul    
    Dg = (4 * Ag) / (Sg + Si)    
    Range("L12").Value = Dg    
    ug = (vsg * t) / Ag    
    Range("M12").Value = ug    
    Rel = (rl * Dl * ul) / mul    
    Range("N12").Value = Rel    
    Reg = (rg * Dg * ug) / mug    
    Range("O12").Value = Reg

    fg = 0.046 * (Reg) ^ (-0.2)    
    Range("Q12").Value = fg    
    fl = 0.046 * (Rel) ^ (-0.2)    
    Range("S12").Value = fl    
    taug = (fg * rg * ((ug) ^ 2)) / 2    
    Range("P12").Value = taug    
    taul = (fl * rl * ((ul) ^ 2)) / 2    
    Range("R12").Value = taul    
    taui = (((ug) ^ 2) * rg * fg) / 2    
    Range("T12").Value = taui

    fx = ((taug * Sg) / Ag) - ((taul * Sl) / Al) + ((taui * Si) * ((1 / Al) + (1 / Ag))) + (rl - rg) * 9.8 * Sin(alpha)    
    Range("U12").Value = fx

End Sub
```

Comment: comment out everything below the code line `Range("U12").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D12")`. Then tell us what doesn't work as you expect. The syntax of your GoalSeek code looks correct but its ability to function depends upon the formula in U12 (which your code later changes to a fixed value which is why that part shouldn't run while you test GoalSeek). You may find it useful to test your GoalSeek formula in the worksheet first, before you transfer its action to VBA.

Comment: BTW, there seems to be no reason for declaring all your variables on module level. Consider placing the declarations inside your sub.

Comment: Please focus on your specific issue and let's start from there. Do you have problem on `Goal Seek` method? Or with the logic and calculations? Please narrow it down for us to better help you.

Comment: Say I have a function. A function of  the form  @Variatus

Comment: OK. Let's say you have a function. You say it is "a function of the form" (whatever that is). I don't think I know enough about this function to be able to comment on it. In fact, I don't know if you carried out the test I suggested, and neither did you tell us about its success or failure, most important, which kind of failure, where in the code, if there was a failure. How can I help you now?

Comment: I understand what your are asking of me. I'm just trying to figure out how to portray it in a manner that actually makes sense. I thought of creating a private chat some where I can elaborate without having to comment too much on here. I'm not sure if giving you my email is permitted. @Variatus

Comment: Please just do as I suggested, "comment out everything below the code line Range("U12").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D12"). Then tell us what doesn't work as you expect." Is there an error in the code? Is the result in the worksheet not what you hoped for?